# Ensemble in h2o (random forest) -multinomial distribution

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, h2o, ensemble-learning

I have a problem with building an ensemble using `h2o` and Random Forest as one of the components. I estimate the models as in `h2o`'s documentation with the only difference being the dependent variable being a multiclass variable. When I try to build an ensemble I get the following error:

```
Error: water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to set the distribution for a multinomial Random Forest classifier.
```

I tried googling it but with no success. Anyone knows what to do in such a case?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code *and* your data

Comment: what version of h2o r are you using? you may need to upgrade to the latest stable release of H2O to get support for multiclass. example code here http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html

Comment: That helped, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiclass support for Stacked Ensemble was only released very recently (in H2O 3.16.0.1), so you'll need to upgrade your H2O package for this to work.

You can use `update.packages("h2o")` to upgrade to the latest CRAN version.